# Python syntax: unpacking multiple variables from function return value in ternary expression gives unexpected result

Tags: python, syntax, ternary-operator, iterable-unpacking

I have noticed an odd problem with unpacking multiple values in a ternary expression. Firstly, a MWE illustrating the syntax, in which the intent is to unpack the tuple on the right and assign the list inside it to the first name on the left, and the number to the second name.

```
condition = False
a, b = [1, 2], 3 if not condition else None, None  # ValueError: too many values to unpack
def foo():
    return [1, 2], 3
([1, 2], 3) == foo()  # True
a, b = foo()  # works as expected: a = [1, 2] and b = 3
a, b = foo() if not condition else None, None  # now a = ([1, 2], 3) and b is None
```

My question is to understand the rationale behind the syntax here. If `condition` evaluates as false, why would the last part of the ternary expression, the `else` clause, ever be evaluated at all? Is Python assigning the second `None` to `b`? This makes no sense to me, but I cannot see how else a) no ValueError is raised to tell me that unpacking has not worked at all (if my syntax somehow compels Python to treat the whole tuple as a single entity rather than unpacking it) and b) a value is nonetheless assigned to `b`. The obvious next tests:

```
a, b = foo() if not condition else None, 'test'  # Now a = ([1, 2], 3) and b = 'test'
a, b = (lambda x: [[1, 2], 3])('blah') if not condition else None, 'test'  # Same result with a lambda function.
```

So it seems that the else clause *is* being evaluated. Why does this happen? Is there an elegant way of rewriting this to allow me to call the function inside such a ternary expression, aside from the obvious and arguably clumsier

```
if not condition:
    a, b = foo()
else:
    a, b = None, None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just precedence. Python is parsing this as:

```
a, b = (foo() if not condition else None), None
```

For your expected result, you'll need to add parentheses around the Nones:

```
a, b = foo() if not condition else (None, None)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will make a strong mental note never to go light on the bracketing again.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here, is python takes your ternary expression, as the first item to be unpacked and `, None` as the second. Same thing with brackets:

```
a, b = (foo() if not condition else None), None
```

This can be mitigated by doing:

```
a, b = foo() if not condition else (None, None)
```

Which will give you the correct result:

```
>>> a, b = foo() if not condition else (None, None)
>>> a, b
([1, 2], 3)
```